# Why do I get "subl: command not found"?

Tags: sublimetext

I am trying to access and manipulate the `.gitignore` file in Sublime via the terminal and I ran into this:

```
subl .gitignore
-bash: subl: command not found
```

Why can't it find it?

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it more readable. It had nothing to do with Ruby or Rails or optimization, only Sublime Text, so I removed the unneeded tags. I also made the title relate to the question, instead of being a distantly related comment.

Answer (score 2):

From [the official documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html):

*The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path, you can run:*

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```